# Atom live server brings up "Not a WebSocket request" message

Tags: atom-editor, manjaro, atom-liveserver

I've been using `atom-live-server` for about a year and everything was fine. But I just updated my Linux Manjaro (as I regularly do at least once a month) and after that `atom-live-server` just stopped working and only brings a white page with message "Not a WebSocket request" on top corner of browser. I tested different ports and projects but nothing changed. 
I didn't find even a similar issue anywhere else. Has anyone have any idea about this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find any similar problem anywhere else; however after some days and updating the whole OS (including atom) and also reinstalling `atom-live-server` the problem is fixed now.